How may I use the ReturnType of a Function as a type for another function?
I'd like to implement a caching system for my TypeScript program. I created a class that holds some get and set functions in order to retrieve and set the values. I specifically am using a function to resolve to the desired value in the event that I might be expired. The logic for that should follow after.
So I came up with this construct here. And it should work
type StoreEntry<T = unknown> = {
    current: T;
    resolve: () => T;
};

type Store = Map<PropertyKey, StoreEntry<any>>;

class Cache {
    private store: Store = new Map();

    constructor() {}

    public set = (key: PropertyKey, resolve: StoreEntry["resolve"]) => {
        this.store.set(key, {
            current: resolve(),
            resolve: resolve
        });
    };

    public get = (key: PropertyKey) => {
        const storeItem = this.store.get(key);

        if (!storeItem) return undefined;

        return storeItem.current as ReturnType<typeof storeItem.resolve>;
    };
}

When trying to write it out however my intellisense is interpreting the result as "unknown"
const cache = new Cache();

cache.set("foo", () => "bar");
const result = cache.get("foo");
/* const result: any */

I would rather have it show the type I used whenever I set the value (string).
Playground

There's no way any change you make to cache will affect the apparent type of const cache2 = Cache.getInstance() even though it will be the same instance. Is that okay? If not, then you're stuck. If so, then you should [edit] the question to just remove the whole static instance part because it's distracting at best (just let people make new instances for the purpose of the question).

In your cache, the keys are not known till runtime, and the type of value corresponding to each key is not known till runtime. I can't see a way to give get a better type without having some constraints on what the cache holds

One could do something like this approach using assertion methods, but it's not really something I'd recommend. OP seems to hope that TS will follow arbitrary mutations but that's not how the language works.  Not sure how to proceed here.

This would require some extreme type-gymnastics like @jcalz showed. If you want the cached 'get' to be specifically typed, then it would be best to just explicity pass that type with get<T>(key: PropertyKey): T | undefined { return foo as T}. Otherwise you'd still need to verify that the type returned is indeed what you expect it to be, regardless of Intellisense telling you it is that type.

@jcalz I haven't actually thought about a const cache2 at any point in time but I understand what you're referring to.
May I ask why exactly you don't recommend the approach you mentioned?
Else I might just pass the type as @KamielDev mentioned. Tho I really hoped to avoid that. Perhaps I also just need to rethink the way I'm doing this.

Assertion methods have all kinds of caveats: they require explicit type annotations (see the added comment here); they can never widen a type, so you can't write cache.set("a", 1); cache.delete("a"); cache.set("a", "x") and change the a property from number to string; they can't return a value so minor changes (e.g., have set() return true or false depending on whether there was an existing value) will break, etc etc etc. If this fully addresses the question I can write an answer or find a suitable duplication source. Let me know.

Yea I believe that would settle it for me :o

TypeScript cannot generally model mutations of a type; it doesn't really track state changes on an instance of a type.  If you try to do this you'll find yourself fighting with TypeScript the whole way.
The closest TypeScript gets to this sort of thing is narrowing, meaning that, in some circumstances, TypeScript can see that the type of some value becomes more specific. If the mutations you care about are all narrowings, then it is conceivably possible to write code that behaves the way you want. It's still likely to be unpleasant though.
Let's say the goal looks like this:
const cache = new MyCache();
cache.get("foo"); // error
cache.set("foo", () => "bar"); // okay
const result = cache.get("foo"); // okay
cache.get("bar"); // error
cache.set("bar", () => 123); // okay
cache.get("bar")?.toFixed(); // okay
cache.get("foo"); // okay

where TypeScript will only allow you to get things you've already set, and it knows the type you set.  This is possible-ish, if you make the set() method act as an assertion function which narrows the instance it's called on to something whose get() method knows about the key.
It would be done this way:
class MyCache<T extends object = {}> {
    private store: Store = new Map();

    constructor() { }

    public set<
        K extends PropertyKey,
        V extends (K extends keyof T ? T[K] : unknown)
    >(key: K, resolve: () => V): asserts this is MyCache<T & Record<K, V>> {
        this.store.set(key, {
            current: resolve(),
            resolve: resolve
        });
    };

    public get<K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
        const storeItem = this.store.get(key) as StoreEntry<T[K]>;
        if (!storeItem) return undefined;
        return storeItem.current;
    };
}

Here MyCache is now generic in an object type T corresponding to the key-value relationship. You will start with Cache<{}> (which is why I made {} the default type argument for T), then if you call set("a", 123) you'd have a Cache<{a: number}>, and then if you call set("b", "xyz") you'd have a Cache<{a: number, b: string}>.
The set() method is generic in K, the type of key, and V, the return type of resolve(). I've constrained K to keylike things, and V to something that checks via conditional type if K is already a known key... if it is, then V has to be compatible with the type already known for that key (otherwise it wouldn't be a narrowing), and if not, then V is unconstrained (the unknown type accepts anything).  Once you call that method, this (the type of the instance) is asserted to Cache<T & Record<K, V>> using Record<K, V> to mean "an object whose properties at keys of type K are of type V" and the intersection to "join" that to the existing T type.
The get() method is now generic also and only allows keys in T. The return type depends on the value type at the key.
Now you get the behavior you want, but only if you explicitly annotate the type of cache:
const cache: MyCache = new MyCache();
//         ^^^^^^^^^ necessary
cache.get("foo"); // error
cache.set("foo", () => "bar"); // okay
const result = cache.get("foo"); // okay
cache.get("bar"); // error
cache.set("bar", () => 123); // okay
cache.get("bar")?.toFixed(); // okay
cache.get("foo"); // okay

That explicit annotation is just one of many caveats here. Assertion functions and methods require such annotations to work, as per the implementation in microsoft/TypeScript#32695. Otherwise you'll just get an error about annotations.
But it least it works.

And again, not something I'd probably want to do in production code. There are lots of caveats. If you decide that Cache should be able to delete, or set something to a different type, then suddenly you can't express what you're doing as narrowing at all. Assertion functions don't let you do that.  So you'd either have to just give up on doing this at all, or refactor so that you don't mutate state of existing instances. You can use a more immutable approach and just return new instances for every set():
class MyCache<T extends object = {}> {
    private store: Store = new Map();

    constructor() { }

    public set<
        K extends PropertyKey,
        V extends (K extends keyof T ? T[K] : unknown)
    >(key: K, resolve: () => V): MyCache<T & Record<K, V>> {
        const ret = new MyCache<T & Record<K, V>>();
        ret.store = new Map(this.store);
        ret.store.set(key, {
            current: resolve(),
            resolve: resolve
        });
        return ret;
    };

    public get<K extends keyof T>(key: K) {
        const storeItem = this.store.get(key) as StoreEntry<T[K]>;
        if (!storeItem) return undefined;
        return storeItem.current;
    };
}

const cache = new MyCache();
cache.get("foo"); // error
const cache2 = cache.set("foo", () => "bar"); // okay
const result = cache2.get("foo"); // okay
cache2.get("bar"); // error
const cache3 = cache2.set("bar", () => 123); // okay
cache3.get("bar")?.toFixed(); // okay
cache3.get("foo"); // okay

You could get away with returning this and not constructing new instances and copying Maps, but then if you re-use a Cache you've already set() you'll get weird behavior. Either way you'd need to think of set() as producing a new thing, and forget about the existing thing. This might not meet your needs, but it's the cleanest way to translate a TypeScript-hostile state-mutating data structure into a TypeScript-friendly form.
Playground link to code
